# PNGs in Delphi 2009 Imagelists and Images

Tags: delphi, png, delphi-2009, imagelist

D2009 introduces PNG support for Images and Imagelists.

However...

I have an imagelist containing png images with alpha. I want to place one of these on a form using a TImage. How do I do this and get the image nicely composited?

As an example of the problem I'm facing the code below fails to work correctly, and produces the effect shown:

```
ImageList.GetBitmap(index, Image1.Picture.Bitmap);
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [clip2net.com](http://clip2net.com/clip/m0/1234439882-clip-5kb.png))</sub>

To explain a bit more:

Drop a Timage on a form, and at design time, load a PNG file with alpha using the Picture property. Note how it is correctly composited with full transparency onto the form.

Now, at design time, add a second empty Timage, add a TImagelist, and add the same PNG to the imagelist. How can I assign the PNG in the TImageList to the second TImage, and have it look identical to the first one?

Comment: Also, that certainly doesn't look like Delphi code.  You sure about the language?

Comment: I second both previous comments. ;)

Comment: @Ken - You're right about C++Builder - I'll tweak the post.

Comment: If you still have the original image, re-uploading it directly to stackoverflow instead of a third party site would be helpful. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

From my research I found that TImageList stores the images as TBitmaps, so the alpha information is lost on storage, and you can't achieve what you're looking for with the current implementation of TImageList.

**Update:**

A little more experiments and with the code below i could make transparency work with the code below.

```
ImageList1.ColorDepth := cd32Bit;
Image2.Transparent := True;
Image2.Canvas.Pen.Style := psClear;
Image2.Canvas.Rectangle(0, 0, Image2.Width+1, Image2.Height+1);
ImageList1.Draw(Image2.Canvas, 0,0,0);
```

But it didn't look as pretty as a loaded png.

Comment: Nope, the alpha information isn't lost. You can use the TImagelist with TButtons and get proper transparent glyphs on the buttons. Besides, bitmaps can be 32 bpp...

Answer (score 2):

Check the Enable Runtime Themes in the tab at
*Project -> Options -> Application tab*

This solved my problem for me in RAD Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried a simple test.  TImageList contains a PNG image with transparency.  I render the image on the second TImage using:

imlImageList.Draw(img2.Canvas, 0, 0, 0);

What made the difference for me was setting img2.Transparent := true (I used the designer, not code).

Comment: That doesn't work for me - I get the same result as shown above. Are you sure your PNG hasd proper soft-edged transparency?

Comment: Alpha transparency becomes simple  BMP-color-as-transparent when used inside TIMageList, as per design of the MS Common Controls library. This is not even Delphi code, it's Windows itself doing it.

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled over this discussion-thread:

[Tranparent PNGs in D2009 TImageList](https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=3172&tstart=0)

> @Pekka Nyyssonen: Setting ColorDepth to cd32Bit and DrawingStyle to dsTransparent 
>   worked for me.

I don't have access to delphi 2009 my self so I havn't tried it out, though...

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to add transparent images to an image list.

With AddMasked or InsertMasked, you add an image and tags a color to be the transparent color:

```
procedure InsertMasked(Index: Integer; Image: TBitmap; MaskColor: TColor);
function AddMasked(Image: TBitmap; MaskColor: TColor): Integer;
```

With Insert or Add, you add an image and a mask. The mask if a 2 color (black/white) image where only the white pixels from the image are used, the others are transparent.

```
function Add(Image, Mask: TBitmap): Integer;
procedure Insert(Index: Integer; Image, Mask: TBitmap);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm after proper alpha blending as the left-hand images shows, not single-bit masking, .

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, this cannot be acheived. None of the suggestions given result in a properly alpha-blended image, which is the primary requirement.

Maybe by defining a class derived from TImageList, which can then access protected methods, something could be got to work. My solution for now is to use a third-party custom ImageList component specifically for this.