# How to copy one PNG from other PNG?

Tags: image, delphi, png, delphi-7

My application needs a lot of PNGs and I often mess up my code while trying to work with them. To make my life easier I made one big PNG image in Realword Paint and pasted all those small PNG images on to it. Now I have one file instead. Now all I need is to copy one PNG on to other with transparency (btw don't ask why), because I need to work with each image induvidually. I am bad programmer when it comes to working with images. I am using Delphi 7.

`PGNImage.Resize`

```
procedure TPngObject.Resize(const CX, CY: Integer);
  function Min(const A, B: Integer): Integer;
  begin
    if A < B then Result := A else Result := B;
  end;
var
  Header: TChunkIHDR;
  Line, NewBytesPerRow: Integer;
  NewHandle: HBitmap;
  NewDC: HDC;
  NewImageData: Pointer;
  NewImageAlpha: Pointer;
  NewImageExtra: Pointer;
begin
  if (CX > 0) and (CY > 0) then
  begin
    {Gets some actual information}
    Header := Self.Header;

    {Creates the new image}
    NewDC := CreateCompatibleDC(Header.ImageDC);
    Header.BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth := cx;
    Header.BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight := cy;
    NewHandle := CreateDIBSection(NewDC, pBitmapInfo(@Header.BitmapInfo)^,
      DIB_RGB_COLORS, NewImageData, 0, 0);
    SelectObject(NewDC, NewHandle);
    {$IFDEF UseDelphi}Canvas.Handle := NewDC;{$ENDIF}
    NewBytesPerRow := (((Header.BitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biBitCount * cx) + 31)
      and not 31) div 8;

    {Copies the image data}
    for Line := 0 to Min(CY - 1, Height - 1) do
      CopyMemory(Ptr(Longint(NewImageData) + (Longint(CY) - 1) *
      NewBytesPerRow - (Line * NewBytesPerRow)), Scanline[Line],
      Min(NewBytesPerRow, Header.BytesPerRow));

    {Build array for alpha information, if necessary}
    if (Header.ColorType = COLOR_RGBALPHA) or
      (Header.ColorType = COLOR_GRAYSCALEALPHA) then
    begin
      GetMem(NewImageAlpha, CX * CY);
      Fillchar(NewImageAlpha^, CX * CY, 255);
      for Line := 0 to Min(CY - 1, Height - 1) do
        CopyMemory(Ptr(Longint(NewImageAlpha) + (Line * CX)),
        AlphaScanline[Line], Min(CX, Width));
      FreeMem(Header.ImageAlpha);
      Header.ImageAlpha := NewImageAlpha;
    end;

    {$IFDEF Store16bits}
    if (Header.BitDepth = 16) then
    begin
      GetMem(NewImageExtra, CX * CY);
      Fillchar(NewImageExtra^, CX * CY, 0);
      for Line := 0 to Min(CY - 1, Height - 1) do
        CopyMemory(Ptr(Longint(NewImageExtra) + (Line * CX)),
        ExtraScanline[Line], Min(CX, Width));
      FreeMem(Header.ExtraImageData);
      Header.ExtraImageData := NewImageExtra;
    end;
    {$ENDIF}

    {Deletes the old image}
    DeleteObject(Header.ImageHandle);
    DeleteDC(Header.ImageDC);

    {Prepares the header to get the new image}
    Header.BytesPerRow := NewBytesPerRow;
    Header.IHDRData.Width := CX;
    Header.IHDRData.Height := CY;
    Header.ImageData := NewImageData;

    {Replaces with the new image}
    Header.ImageHandle := NewHandle;
    Header.ImageDC := NewDC;
  end
  else
    {The new size provided is invalid}
    RaiseError(EPNGInvalidNewSize, EInvalidNewSize)

end;
```

`SmoothResize` by Gustavo Daud

```
procedure SmoothResize(apng:tpngobject; NuWidth,NuHeight:integer);
var
  xscale, yscale         : Single;
  sfrom_y, sfrom_x       : Single;
  ifrom_y, ifrom_x       : Integer;
  to_y, to_x             : Integer;
  weight_x, weight_y     : array[0..1] of Single;
  weight                 : Single;
  new_red, new_green     : Integer;
  new_blue, new_alpha    : Integer;
  new_colortype          : Integer;
  total_red, total_green : Single;
  total_blue, total_alpha: Single;
  IsAlpha                : Boolean;
  ix, iy                 : Integer;
  bTmp : TPNGObject;
  sli, slo : pRGBLine;
  ali, alo: pbytearray;
begin
  if not (apng.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_RGBALPHA, COLOR_RGB]) then
    raise Exception.Create('Only COLOR_RGBALPHA and COLOR_RGB formats' +
    ' are supported');
  IsAlpha := apng.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_RGBALPHA];
  if IsAlpha then new_colortype := COLOR_RGBALPHA else
    new_colortype := COLOR_RGB;
  bTmp := Tpngobject.CreateBlank(new_colortype, 8, NuWidth, NuHeight);
  xscale := bTmp.Width / (apng.Width-1);
  yscale := bTmp.Height / (apng.Height-1);
  for to_y := 0 to bTmp.Height-1 do begin
    sfrom_y := to_y / yscale;
    ifrom_y := Trunc(sfrom_y);
    weight_y[1] := sfrom_y - ifrom_y;
    weight_y[0] := 1 - weight_y[1];
    for to_x := 0 to bTmp.Width-1 do begin
      sfrom_x := to_x / xscale;
      ifrom_x := Trunc(sfrom_x);
      weight_x[1] := sfrom_x - ifrom_x;
      weight_x[0] := 1 - weight_x[1];

      total_red   := 0.0;
      total_green := 0.0;
      total_blue  := 0.0;
      total_alpha  := 0.0;
      for ix := 0 to 1 do begin
        for iy := 0 to 1 do begin
          sli := apng.Scanline[ifrom_y + iy];
          if IsAlpha then ali := apng.AlphaScanline[ifrom_y + iy];
          new_red := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtRed;
          new_green := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtGreen;
          new_blue := sli[ifrom_x + ix].rgbtBlue;
          if IsAlpha then new_alpha := ali[ifrom_x + ix];
          weight := weight_x[ix] * weight_y[iy];
          total_red   := total_red   + new_red   * weight;
          total_green := total_green + new_green * weight;
          total_blue  := total_blue  + new_blue  * weight;
          if IsAlpha then total_alpha  := total_alpha  + new_alpha  * weight;
        end;
      end;
      slo := bTmp.ScanLine[to_y];
      if IsAlpha then alo := bTmp.AlphaScanLine[to_y];
      slo[to_x].rgbtRed := Round(total_red);
      slo[to_x].rgbtGreen := Round(total_green);
      slo[to_x].rgbtBlue := Round(total_blue);
      if isAlpha then alo[to_x] := Round(total_alpha);
    end;
  end;
  apng.Assign(bTmp);
  bTmp.Free;
end;
```

Thanks a lot, Have a nice day!

Comment: Don't shoot me for asking, but why not just dump all the individual PNGs into a Resource File and load them as needed from that instead? It's one file when you're done, and gets packed into the resource space of your executable... one line of code to load the stored PNGs, easy as it gets no?

Comment: Well, then one approach (though not the most elegant, I'm sure) would be to iterate X and Y of the segment, then replicate the pixel colour (RGBA to retain Alpha) onto your new PNG container instance. This of course would require you to know the Top, Bottom, Left and Right co-ordinates of your "segments".

Comment: @LaKren I know all this, but the problem that I am dumb, I don't know how to do this, I am asking for code. I don't want to be rude but I just can't do anything without code. I am not lazy, I am noob when working with images at this level...

Comment: @Roberts, it depends on what library will you use. We can't provide you a code sample when you don't have a library chosen. A sidenote for those who wants to see how to copy such image, take a look inside the `TPNGImage.Resize` function.

Comment: @TLama What library? PNGImage the newest one 1.564. If I understand correctly. I have problems with english...

Comment: Then before me (or someone else) post a code sample here, take a look into that `TPNGImage.Resize` function. The only modification you will have to do is to start the iterations not from 0 but from coordinates you specify.

Comment: @TLama Oh, that's briliant. Done

Comment: Glad this discussion got you the result you needed :)

Comment: @TLama I don't understand what you just said. I want somebody or you to give at least a part of the code... I am a noob

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one sample code modified from a 'SlicePNG' (*"This function slices a large PNG file (e.g. an image with all images for a toolbar) into smaller, equally-sized pictures"*) procedure found [elsewhere](http://vcl-styles-utils.googlecode.com/svn-history/r18/trunk/Extras/PngFunctions.pas):

```
procedure CropPNG(Source: TPNGObject; Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer;
    out Target: TPNGObject);

  function ColorToTriple(Color: TColor): TRGBTriple;
  begin
    Color := ColorToRGB(Color);
    Result.rgbtBlue := Color shr 16 and $FF;
    Result.rgbtGreen := Color shr 8 and $FF;
    Result.rgbtRed := Color and $FF;
  end;

var
   X, Y: Integer;
   Bitmap: TBitmap;
   BitmapLine: PRGBLine;
   AlphaLineA, AlphaLineB: pngimage.PByteArray;
begin
  if (Source.Width < (Left + Width)) or (Source.Height < (Top + Height)) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid position/size');

  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.Width := Width;
    Bitmap.Height := Height;
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf24bit;

    for Y := 0 to Bitmap.Height - 1 do begin
      BitmapLine := Bitmap.Scanline[Y];
      for X := 0 to Bitmap.Width - 1 do
        BitmapLine^[X] := ColorToTriple(Source.Pixels[Left + X, Top + Y]);
    end;

    Target := TPNGObject.Create;
    Target.Assign(Bitmap);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;

  if Source.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_GRAYSCALEALPHA, COLOR_RGBALPHA] then begin
    Target.CreateAlpha;
    for Y := 0 to Target.Height - 1 do begin
      AlphaLineA := Source.AlphaScanline[Top + Y];
      AlphaLineB := Target.AlphaScanline[Y];
      for X := 0 to Target.Width - 1 do
        AlphaLineB^[X] := AlphaLineA^[X + Left];
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Sample call:

```
var
  Png: TPNGObject;
  CroppedPNG: TPNGobject;
begin
  PNG := TPNGObject.Create;
  PNG.LoadFromFile('..\test.png');

  CropPNG(PNG, 30, 10, 60, 50, CroppedPNG);
  CroppedPNG.SaveToFile('..\croptest.png');
```

Comment: @Sertac, now thinking about it, wouldn't be possible to use the `StretchDIBits` and modify the image header only ?

Comment: +1 for the simplicity.  @TLama, I also believe that this could be done without the use of `TBitmap`, by starting up with `CreateBlank` and copying the `Scanline` and `AlphaScanline` to the new PNG. but I'm too lazy to actually try anything today ;)

Answer (score 13):

Here is another version (It works very fast):

```
procedure CropPNG(Source: TPNGObject; Left, Top, Width, Height: Integer;
  out Target: TPNGObject);
var
  IsAlpha: Boolean;
  Line: Integer;
begin
  if (Source.Width < (Left + Width)) or (Source.Height < (Top + Height)) then
    raise Exception.Create('Invalid position/size');

  Target := TPNGObject.CreateBlank(Source.Header.ColorType, 
    Source.Header.BitDepth, Width, Height);
  IsAlpha := Source.Header.ColorType in [COLOR_GRAYSCALEALPHA, COLOR_RGBALPHA];
  for Line := 0 to Target.Height - 1 do
  begin
    if IsAlpha then
      CopyMemory(Target.AlphaScanline[Line], 
        Ptr(LongInt(Source.AlphaScanline[Line + Top]) + LongInt(Left)), 
        Target.Width);
    CopyMemory(Target.Scanline[Line], 
      Ptr(LongInt(Source.Scanline[Line + Top]) + LongInt(Left * 3)), 
      Target.Width * 3);
  end;
end;
```

**Note:** The above code is compatible with the newer [`pngimage`](http://theunknownones.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Libraries/PNGSupport/pngimage.pas) Version 1.56+ (which supports the `CreateBlank` constructor)

Comment: @Sertac's method will not "fail". It works good actually. I only  shared an alternative which does not involves a middle `TBitmap` and should be faster.

Comment: I tested it time ago, I just saying that if there will be any problems, maybe I will use yours.

Comment: I wish I had not put that rather pointless check in the beginning. Anyway, this is really nice!

Comment: Hey, I have a problem, when I try to use this function in DLL executed from application it raises exception "no valid header found" bla bla bla. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried writing code to just *load* a png using [libpng](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=libpng&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDUQFjAA&url=http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html&ei=q0GeT6O2D8uQiQfthZmuDg&usg=AFQjCNEiBZsLgAdOKVLw_rgsG_81P3Euzg&cad=rja).  It's pretty horrible to work with.

Try using [imlib2](http://docs.enlightenment.org/api/imlib2/html/) to take care of translating PNG files. it has a [Delphi binding](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid08582865A26A809A6A0B1E0CEE04493F029B2DE0.aspx?s=tlist%20record#L310), apparently.

If if you get really stuck you could use [Inage Magick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)'s separate executable to do the image cropping.