# How do I load an animated cursor from a multi-frame PNG image?

Tags: delphi, png

How do I load an animated cursor from a single PNG with 32 frames?

Here is my PNG:

[image]

I tried to convert it into an ANI cursor by using AniTuner, but the cursor appears much smaller than the original frame from the PNG. Is there a way in Delphi to create an animated cursor from a single PNG with multiple frames inside?

I have read the following Stack Overflow post: [Clipping a filmstrip in png format (Delphi 2010)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391069/clipping-a-filmstrip-in-png-format-delphi-2010)

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Delphi? Surely you just need a tool for making cursors.

Answer (score 2):

The problem you are facing is that by Default the mouse cursor size on Windows is 32x32 pixels unless windows theme is changed to enable large mouse cursors (accessability options).

Now because of this limitation AniTuner probably automatically scales the cursor down to 32x32 size. So you just might wanna try to find some other program capable of converting GIF animations into ANI animations while maintaining the image size.

There is a solution of how to use cursor larger than 32x32 hre on Stack Owerflow but unfortunately it is written for C# and not Delphi. Maybe you could translate it into Delphi.

[How to override maximum 32x32 mouse size in Windows like this program can](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13688159/how-to-override-maximum-32x32-mouse-size-in-windows-like-this-program-can)

Comment: big thanks to Mister : Rob Kennedy and Mister : Blobby  for Editing our Messages ..,Mister : SilverWarior and David Heffernan your replys its makes me very happy and about your suggestion of Making cursors Mister : David Heffernan i treated as a second help for me in this time because i tired on seaching the tools here that allowed me to Make Big animated cursors , and about your Suggestion Mister : SilverWarior..due to the different language between Delphi and C# i can't solve My Problem by converting C# code into delphi,it is so hard than solving My problem under delphi ..